# Immediately update DataGridViewCheckBoxCell

Tags: winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcheckboxcell

I am programmatically updating my WinForm DataGridView

Problem, DataGridViewCheckBoxCell doesn't get updated !!!

I was google, it seams like knowing case but whatever I've tried did not help yet.

```
 private void InitializeFunctionsDataGrid()
    {


        System.Data.DataSet ds = func.GetFunctions();



        this.FunctionsDataGrid.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        this.FunctionsDataGrid.Columns["FunctionId"].Visible = false;
        this.FunctionsDataGrid.Columns["DESCRIPTION"].Width = 370;


         DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn column = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
            column.Name = "enable";
            column.HeaderText = "enable";
            column.FalseValue = 0;
            column.TrueValue = 1;
            FunctionsDataGrid.Columns.Add(column);



        foreach(DataGridViewRow row in FunctionsDataGrid.Rows)
        {

                 (( DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells["enable"]).Value = 1;

        }

       FunctionsDataGrid.CurrentCell = null;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK basically easiest way for me was to work with datasource.
I've add the column to the DataTable and fill it with data.
And then last thing this.FunctionsDataGrid.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

Answer (score 0):

`enable` is an unbound column. This means that you need to provide cell value yourself.

You can set the [VirtualMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.virtualmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to true and handle the [CellValueNeeded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalueneeded%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event.
If you want to enable the user to check a cell then you need to handle the [CellValuePushed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluepushed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event. 
DataGridView samples that are part of the [DataGridView FAQ](http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/6/4/5646742C-3EB7-48F7-BFB3-CC295D618CF9/DataGridView%20FAQ.doc) has a specific example of an unbound checkbox column along with databound columns.